# In Excel Create Multiple Dependent Drop Down Lists Based on Another Drop Down

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Is there any way to make multiple Drop Down Lists based on only ONE other Drop Down List?**

My experience when working with Dependent Drop Down Lists is that for each new Drop Down you create you have to narrow down. I am looking for a way to stay at the same level.

If I select Banana, the Drop Down Lists "Size(Length)", "Size(Diameter)" and "Weight" should all be based on Product column.

I have made a list called "banana" but that one can only be linked to either "Size(Length)", "Size(Diameter)" or"Weight"

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGEvc.png]

Comment: That sounds like you would benefit from a lookup table, this can be on a hidden tab if you don't want the end-user to see it. You can then have the 3 fields returned by simple `INDEX(MATCH())` or `VLOOKUP()`

Comment: Yes, I found a way with index and vlookup.

Comment: Awesome, feel free to answer your own question, you'll even earn for a badge for doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to create dependent Drop Down Lists on the same level. Typically, each Drop Down List will narrow down the selection every time you select a value from a list. Instead of using this approach I used this formula and only created one Drop Down List.

=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$2000; SMALL(IF($T$1=$O$2:$O$2000; MATCH(ROW($O$2:$O$2000); ROW($O$2:$O$2000)); ""); ROW(O1))); "")